# Android support Toolbar with windowTranslucentStatus and windowActionModeOverlay

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-toolbar, android-support-design

I'm building an Android application using AppCompatActivities and Material Design Support Library.
I'm stucking into two problems:

**android:windowTranslucentStatus**

I've set windows:windowTranslucentStatus to true in my style and then enabled fitsSystemWindows in the root element of my activity. The problem is that the status bar become gray colored (see the screenshot below)

[image]

Here is my layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".app.activity.LoginActivityBase"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- Login progress -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/login_status_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="@string/login_progress_signing_in"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Login form -->
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            style="@style/LoginFormContainer">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/appLogo"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
                />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                    android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                    android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                    android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

                <LinearLayout
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp">
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
                        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight=".5"
                        android:text="@string/Cancel"/>
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
                        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight=".5"
                        android:layout_gravity="end"
                        android:paddingLeft="32dp"
                        android:paddingRight="32dp"
                        android:text="@string/action_sign_in_short" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/register_button"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:paddingLeft="32dp"
                android:paddingRight="32dp"
                android:text="@string/action_register_short" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I solve this?

**android:windowActionModeOverlay**

I've set android:windowActionModeOverlay to true in my AppTheme but when some text is selected the action mode bar does not overlay the toolbar (see screenshot below)

[image]

How can I solve this instead?

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Hi @Androidian did you find any solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Set this in your theme:
**`<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>`**

and the `ActionMode` will be shown over the action bar instead of pushing it down. (If you're not using the latest `AppCompat` then you need to add the "android:" prefix to the property). It basically lets `AppCompat` know that you have a toolbar located in the top of the screen and that it should draw the `ActionMode` on top of it.